# jquery input validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have an input which can accept a combination of data in this format:

dddd.nnnn

where d is an uppercase letter and n is a digit.

In some cases the initial uppercase letters could be 2, 3 or 4 in length. Then a . (point) can be entered, after which only numbers (0 - 9) can be entered.

Some sample entries are as follows

```
GHD.23
GH.235
EFF.1234
```

Can this be done by combining Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 7):

Your regex would be,

```
^[A-Z]{2,4}\.\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xX8nE5/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[A-Z]{2,4}` Allows 2 or 3 or 4 uppercase letters.
- `\.` A literal dot.
- `\d+` One or more digits.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.